# Test ACtivity App Crashes Everytime? Any Ideas Why?

Tags: android, android-activity

My Test test app has just an activity as this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myxml);
    }

    public void myAct(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, One.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

And I have a `Button` with id `mybutton` on `myxml.xml` file. Crashed Everytime. But, i

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

The app starts.
I even tried keeping `android:onClick` on the XML but does not work. I know I have made a silly error, but where?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

should be in `onCreate` after `setContentView`

```
Button button1 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myxml);
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
}
```

You need to set the layout to the activity first and then initialize views. `findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current view hierarchy.

Comment: Great, I was just trying to build a house before buying the land. I got it. Thank you!

Comment: @TikaDattaPahadi you are welcome but why do you need to initialize when you have `android:onClick`. you could get rid of the initialization and it should still work

Comment: @TikaDattaPahadi `Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton)` removing this and having `android:onClick=myAct` will work

Answer (score 1):

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
```

always widget casting come after setcontent view